# media is write protected azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to attach a data disk to an Azure VM. I'm able to create the disk and initialize, however, when I try to write to the new disk, I get an error that it is write protected.

I'm logged in as an administrator.

I've looked at Diskpart, and it says that the drive is not readonly.

I'm lost as to what to do.

Comment: What is your Windows OS?  Could you show your error log as a screenshot?

Comment: The VM is running Windows 10. There are no errors populated in the event viewer when I try to create a folder in that location using a command prompt, just a message that the "media is write protected"

Comment: Could you try add a new disk and try again?  Do you use managed disk or unmanaged disk?  You could do this according to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal) steps.

Comment: I've tried deleting the disk and adding a new one, using those steps that you linked to. I also tried doing it through PowerShell. Every time, the disk is locked and I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I figured it out. The drive needed to be encrypted since we use BitLocker. Looks like I can write to it now.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Login with VM's username and password.

Comment: Yep, tried that. Logged in as a local administrator and logged in as our network's global administrator.